# Why does "paragraph reference component" show empty tiles (Geometrixx example)?

Tags: java, javascript, aem, sling

I use "paragraph reference component" to include pages/subpages. Why does this component show empty tiles (see the attached pic for Geometrixx)? Can it be configured sothat empty tiles not shows?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[Reference](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/wcm/default_components/editmode.html#Reference) component displays contents of the external paragraph system (ie. parsys from a different page). Its browse dialog consists of page tree on the left and tiles presenting paragraph systems belonging to the selected page on the right.

Attached picture presents dialog with *Contact* page selected. Apparently, this page contains 3 paragraph systems. The first one is probably the main parsys, containing text component filled with the contact information. I think there are two reasons why the second and the third tiles are blank:

- they are presenting contents of the empty paragraph systems,
- they are referencing [Inheritance Paragraph Systems](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/wcm/default_components/designmode.html#Inheritance%20Paragraph%20System%20%28iparsys%29) which is not compatible with the *Reference* component.

I don't think there is an out-of-the-box configuration allowing to hide such empty parsys tiles.

Comment: Which TBH sounds like a bug — either it should remove them for reference itself, or it should explicity list them as empty parsys, with something to differentiation them (e.g. the Parsys name).

Comment: I can imagine a situation when you want to reference an empty parsys (eg. you'll put some content there later). Parsys name is often *parsys*, so maybe a relative path would be more useful.

Comment: Me too, though I can't imagine when I'd want to reference one & have to guess which empty parsys I was referencing — especially as a content editor :)

Comment: Now to to print the path instead of empty parsys?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on from **Tomek's** answer above, the Reference component is using a `paragraphreference` xtype, which is defined under `/libs/cq/ui/widgets/source/widgets/form/ParagraphReference.js`.

If you create an overlay, you should be able to change the defined behaviour for an empty parsys. Within the xtype defined in ParagraphReference.js, there is a function, `onSelectPage`:

```
function(node, event) {
    this.proxy.api["read"].url =
        CQ.HTTP.externalize(node.getPath() + ".paragraphs.json", true);
    this.store.reload();
}
```

From this, it seems that CQ is using a `paragraphs` selector to get back specific content from a page, e.g. take a look at "/content/geometrixx/en.paragraphs.json". Here is a sample JSON object returned by this request:

```
{
    "paragraphs": [{
        "path": "/content/geometrixx/en/jcr:content/par/image",
        "html": "\n\n\n\n<div class=\"genericImage\">\n\n    \n    \n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\t <img src=\"/content/dam/geometrixx/portraits/jane_doe.jpg/_jcr_content/renditions/original\" alt=\"Jane Doe\" class=\"cq-dd-image\" title=\"Jane Doe\"/>\n\t\t\n\t\n    "
    }, {
        "path": "/content/geometrixx/en/jcr:content/par/title_1",
        "html": "<h2>Strategic Consulting<\/h2>\n"
    }, {
        "path": "/content/geometrixx/en/jcr:content/par/text_1",
        "html": "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n<div class=\"copy\">&lt;p&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;Apple-style-span&quot; style=&quot;font-size: 12px;&quot;&gt;In&amp;nbsp;today's competitive market, organizations can face several key geometric challenges:&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;<br>&lt;ul&gt;<br>&lt;li&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;Apple-style-span&quot; style=&quot;font-size: 12px;&quot;&gt;Polyhedral Sectioning&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/li&gt;<br>&lt;li&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;Apple-style-span&quot; style=&quot;font-size: 12px;&quot;&gt;Triangulation&amp;nbsp;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/li&gt;<br>&lt;li&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;Apple-style-span&quot; style=&quot;font-size: 12px;&quot;&gt;Trigonometric Calculation&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/li&gt;<br>&lt;li&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;Apple-style-span&quot; style=&quot;font-size: 12px;&quot;&gt;Ruler and Compass Construction&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/li&gt;<br>&lt;/ul&gt;<br>&lt;p&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;Apple-style-span&quot; style=&quot;font-size: 12px;&quot;&gt;&lt;br/&gt;<br>Geometrixx is ready to help your organization deal effectively with all these challenges through our award winning geometric consulting services.&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;<br>&lt;p style=&quot;font-family: tahoma, arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;&quot;&gt;&lt;/p&gt;<br><\/div>\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n<p>\n\n\n<\/p>\n\n"
    }, {
        "path": "/content/geometrixx/en/jcr:content/par/image_0",
        "html": "\n\n\n\n<div class=\"genericImage\">\n\n    \n    \n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\t <img src=\"/content/dam/geometrixx/offices/clean_room.jpg/_jcr_content/renditions/original\" alt=\"Men at Work in the Clean Room\" class=\"cq-dd-image\" title=\"Men at Work in the Clean Room\"/>\n\t\t\n\t\n    "
    }, {
        "path": "/content/geometrixx/en/jcr:content/par/title_2",
        "html": "<h2>Shape Technology<\/h2>\n"
    }, {
        "path": "/content/geometrixx/en/jcr:content/par/text_0",
        "html": "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n<div class=\"copy\"><p>The Geometrixx investment in R&amp;D has done more than solidify our industry leadership role, we have now outpaced our competitors to such an extent that we are in an altogether new space.<\/p>\n<p>This is why our high quality polygons and polyhedra provide the only turnkey solutions across the whole range of euclidean geometry. And our mathematicians are working on the next generation of fractal curves to bring you shapes that are unthinkable today.<\/p>\n<p><\/p>\n<p><\/p>\n\n\n            <\/div>\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n<p>\n\n\n<\/p>\n\n"
    }, {
        "path": "/content/geometrixx/en/jcr:content/rightpar/teaser",
        "html": "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\nCQURLInfo = {\n    \"contextPath\": null,\n    \"requestPath\": '\\/content\\/geometrixx\\/en\\/jcr:content\\/rightpar\\/teaser',\n    \"selectorString\": null,\n    \"selectors\": [],\n    \"extension\": 'html',\n    \"suffix\": null,\n    \"systemId\": '5859bb1d-dee4-484f-ac0d-d83dc1c013ed',\n    \"runModes\": 'lbi,dev,publish'\n};<\/script>\n<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"/etc/clientlibs/foundation/librarymanager.js\"><\/script>\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">\nCQClientLibraryManager.write([{\"p\":\"/etc/clientlibs/foundation/jquery.js\",\"c\":[]},{\"p\":\"/etc/clientlibs/foundation/shared.js\",\"c\":[]},{\"p\":\"/etc/clientlibs/foundation/jquery-ui.js\",\"c\":[]},{\"p\":\"/etc/clientlibs/foundation/personalization/jcarousel.css\",\"c\":[]},{\"p\":\"/etc/clientlibs/foundation/personalization/jcarousel.js\",\"c\":[]},{\"p\":\"/etc/clientlibs/foundation/personalization.js\",\"c\":[]},{\"p\":\"/etc/clientlibs/foundation/jquery-ui/themes/default.css\",\"c\":[]},{\"p\":\"/etc/clientlibs/foundation/personalization/themes/default.css\",\"c\":[]},{\"p\":\"/etc/clientlibs/foundation/personalization/ie6/themes/default.css\",\"c\":[\"ie6\"]}],false);\n<\/script>\n<script type=\"text/javascript\">$CQ(function() {initializeTeaserLoader([{\"path\":\"/content/campaigns/geometrixx/scott-recommends\",\"name\":\"scott-recommends\",\"title\":\"Scott Recommends\",\"campainName\":\"geometrixx\",\"thumbnail\":\"/content/campaigns/geometrixx/scott-recommends/jcr:content/par/image.img.png\",\"id\":\"geometrixx_scott-recommends\",\"segments\":[\"/etc/segmentation/geometrixx/male\"],\"tags\":[]},{\"path\":\"/content/campaigns/geometrixx/yolanda-recommends\",\"name\":\"yolanda-recommends\",\"title\":\"Yolanda Recommends\",\"campainName\":\"geometrixx\",\"thumbnail\":\"/content/campaigns/geometrixx/yolanda-recommends/jcr:content/par/image.img.png\",\"id\":\"geometrixx_yolanda-recommends\",\"segments\":[\"/etc/segmentation/geometrixx/female\"],\"tags\":[]},{\"path\":\"/content/campaigns/geometrixx/default_teaser\",\"name\":\"default_teaser\",\"title\":\"Default Teaser\",\"campainName\":\"geometrixx\",\"thumbnail\":\"/content/campaigns/geometrixx/default_teaser/jcr:content/par/image.img.png\",\"id\":\"geometrixx_default_teaser\",\"segments\":[],\"tags\":[]}], \"first\", \"_content_geometrixx_en_jcr_content_rightpar_teaser\", \"false\", \"http://localhost:4502/libs/wcm/stats/tracker\", \"/content/geometrixx/en/jcr:content/rightpar/teaser\");\n        });<\/script><div id=\"_content_geometrixx_en_jcr_content_rightpar_teaser\" class=\"campaign campaign-geometrixx\"><noscript><div class=\"par parsys\"><div class=\"title section\"><h3>Get the Geometrixx App<\/h3>\n<\/div>\n<div class=\"text module shadow section imagetext\">\n\n\n\n\n\n\n<div class=\"copy\"><p>All things Geometrixx, anytime, anywhere. Our mobile app is is as groundbreaking and remarkably easy-to-use as our shapes. <\/p><p><\/p>\n\n            <\/div>\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n<p>\n\n\n<\/p>\n\n<\/div>\n\n\n\n\n<div class=\"genericImage\">\n\n    \n    \n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\t <img src=\"/content/dam/geometrixx/banners/mobile.jpg/_jcr_content/renditions/original\" alt=\"Geometrixx App\" class=\"cq-dd-image\" title=\"Geometrixx App\"/>\n\t\t\n\t\n    <\/div>\n<\/div>\n<\/noscript><\/div>"
    }],
    "count": 7
}
```

So maybe use this selector to check out the content of the page currently coming back with blank parsys by using the `paragraphs.json` selector, (it seems that you need to be authenticated to hit this endpoint).

If is the "html" property of these objects that is blank, you could extend the `onSelectPage` function in your overlayed version to loop through the array of parsys & copy it's "path" property value to its "html" property for these nodes.